# how to center image in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-mobile

I need to have in my mobile website an image in the start of the page and in the middle , like the image below:

[image]

How can i accomplish that in jquery mobile? I need a solution that will place the image always in the middle no matter what screen(mobile) the user uses. Also is there a way that the image will look bigger or smaller according to the screen? Like adopt in every different screen?

From the jquery mobile site , when i use the codiqa to create an image in the start of the page and in the middle the code looks like this :

```
<div style="width: 288px; height: 100px; position: relative; background-color: #fbfbfb; border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;">
            <img src="http://codiqa.com/static/images/v2/image.png" alt="image" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -18px">
</div>
```

However is not positioned correct and also the margins are in pixels insteaf of percentage , which i guess is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is misleading, you want to center it according to what? Its parent DIV or page content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5T78X/

**HTML :**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: #fbfbfb; border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;">
                <img src="http://codiqa.com/static/images/v2/image.png" alt="image" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -18px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more like it: http://jsfiddle.net/5T78X/28/

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <figure id="topimg">
            <img src="http://codiqa.com/static/images/v2/image.png" alt="image" />
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#topimg {
    text-align: center; /* center the image */
    margin: 1em; 
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#topimg img {
    display: inline-block;  /* treat the img like text */
    max-width: 60px; /*resolution of the img*/
    width: 10%; /* shrink to 10% if lower than 60px */
    margin: 3em auto;  /* add space between top and bottom edge of container */
}
```

I'm assuming `[data-role="page"] { width: 100%; margin:0;}` is still set.

Mixing in styles into the markup is strongly discouraged. Also shifting images around with fixed positioning and discrete pixel values didn't look that right to me.

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```